# Style <meter> tag in latest Opera version

Tags: css, html, browser, opera, meter

I'm currently trying to style a `<meter>` tag in all major browsers: IE7-9, FF, Chrome, Safari and even Opera. I've managed to remove the default `<meter>` styling by using the following CSS code:

```
meter::-webkit-meter-bar, meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value, meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value, meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value {
  background: 0;
}
```

This technique works fine in all mentioned browsers, except Opera! It keeps showing the default green meter. Any idea on how to "destyle" the `<meter>` tag in Opera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way yet to style such elements in Opera. There is a proposal called [Component Object Model](http://dglazkov.github.com/component-model/) which will obliquely allow us to do such styling when it is in a Working Draft, but we are not close to one.

Webkit has implemented a method that is not in any standard and just a suggestion, and I wouldn't assume this is how it would in the future. Most likely these pseudo-element names would change.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start: shouldn't it be `background: transparent;` or `background: inherit;`? See the [background property in HTML Dog](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/background/).

---

I think you're misunderstanding. The `meter::-webkit-meter-bar` selector should have no effect at all on IE, FF and Opera since the `-webkit` part is a selector for Webkit. Chrome and Safari use Webkit as a render engine, but FF uses Gecko, Opera uses Presto, etc.

For FF you would probably need something like `-moz-meter-bar`...
For Opera I do not know. [This Opera community page](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto29/css/o-vendor/)  seems to imply that the prefix would be `-o` rather than `-webkit` or `-moz`.
Good luck.

It's also a good practice to include the "normal" selector when adding such rules.
(And if you're lucky, this might just make it work in Opera.)

```
meter::-webkit-meter-bar,
meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value,
meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value,
meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value,
meter::meter-bar,
meter::meter-optimum-value,
meter::meter-suboptimum-value,
meter::meter-even-less-good-value {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: You could also use `transparent` and `inherit`, but when I'm using shorthand, `0` suffices. See http://www.evotech.net/blog/2008/08/css-background-properties/#bg6. It'll only recognise the background-position this way and uses `transparent` as default background-color anyhow. Besides, `0` is the shortest value. It saves space :).

Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work. I'll try to dig deeper!

P.S. I know those -webkit selectors are only used for Safari and Chrome :). FF and IE don't need any resetting so far

Comment: Ah, true, clever to use bg-position.

Comment: :) Thanks for your post by the way. If I see a solution popping up, I'll post it here.